# Limits of Indeterminate Powers in Exponential Form using L'Hopital's Rule

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, indeterminate-forms

I am trying to find the limit as $x \rightarrow 0$ of $x^x$ using L'Hopital's rule. I have written it in exponential form: $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} e^{x \ln x}$. I do not know how to put it in indeterminate form.

Comment: Technically, you're taking the limit as $x \rightarrow 0^+$ since $x^x$ is only defined for $x > 0$.

Answer (score 4):

$$x^x=\exp{\ln x\over (1/x)}$$ Taking derivatives on top and bottom gives $$\frac{1/x}{-1/x^2}=-x$$ So the function tends to $$\lim_{x\to 0}{e^{-x}}=e^0=1$$ Also note that this should be a one-sided limit.